# Returning list of count and grouped by id linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table that's call checklist:

```
public class CHECKLIST{
[Key]
public int CL_ID { get; set; }

public EmpID { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to return a list that looks like below.

```
EMPID   COUNT
1       5
2       7
3       10
```

I am trying to write the repository as a Dictionary and get an error at g=> g.Count of cannot convert lambda expression to type IEqualityComparer because it's not a delegate type:

```
    public Dictionary<int, int> GetAllComplaintsCount()
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.Checklists
                .GroupBy(a => a.MonitorEnteredEmpID)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Could not get am with checklist", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change this:

```
ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count);
```

to the following:

```
ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

you will get that you want. The reason why you should do this relies on the result the `GroupBy` returns. According to the [specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)

> The group clause returns a **sequence** of IGrouping
>   objects that contain zero or more items that match the key value for
>   the group. For example, you can group a sequence of strings according
>   to the first letter in each string. In this case, the first letter is
>   the key and has a type char, and is stored in the Key property of each
>   IGrouping object. The compiler infers the type of the
>   key.

That you want is to get the number of the items in each group. Since you have a sequence you can get the number of the items in the sequence by calling the `Count` method.